# How do I make the last Menu Item is not a link in TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want to make menu's last element is `javascript:void(0);` last `<li>` of `a` tag is void(0);

I want exactly like this

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=12">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=13">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=14">Service</a></li>
        <li id="top2"><a href="javascript:void(0);" >UP</a></li>
</ul>
```

How it posssible using typoscript ?  i added my typoscript here

```
lib.Footer_menu = COA
lib.Footer_menu{

       10 = HMENU
       10.special = directory
       10.special.value = 12
       10
       {
           wrap = <ul class="col-left-menu">|</ul>
           1 = TMENU
           1{
               expAll = 1
               noBlur = 1
               NO{

               doNotLinkIt = 1
               allWrap = <a href="javascript:void(0);"> | </a>
               stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
               wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>||<li>|</li>||<li>|</li>||<li>|</li>
            }
            ACT < .NO
            ACT = 1
            ACT {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>||<li>|</li>||<li>|</li>||<li id="top">|</li> 
            }
            IFSUB < .NO
            IFSUB = 1
            IFSUB {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>||<li>|</li>||<li>|</li>||<li id="top">|</li> 
            }
            ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
            ACTIFSUB = 1
            ACTIFSUB {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active dropdown">|</li> 
               stdWrap.wrap = <b class="caret"></b>    
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I got solution using jquery  changing href value  :)

Comment: You could also just add a fake menu item at the end, which has no corresponding page in the page tree. Alternatively, you could add pages with type "external link" into the page tree, and set the external link to `javascript:void(0)`, and the protocol to `auto`.

Comment: I tried this but it's not worked but i got solution using j query :)  By the way Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypoScript for rendering this li
include this in TMENU section

```
stdWrap.append = TEXT
stdWrap.append.value = <li id="top2"><a href="javascript:void(0);" >UP</a></li>
```

Comment: it apends all <li> elements not last one and thank you for answer :)

Comment: use this in TMENU and not in NO. so this should work